# How do I test collision for a rotated object in openGl

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d

I wrote a simple program that consists of two cubes colliding.
When I move'em around and test for collisions, it works just fine, but when I rotate a cube, the collision is messed up.
I understand that it happens because openGL does not change my object coordinates, so, how can I accomplish this?

I tried calculating new coordinates like this:

```
new.x = coordinates.x * cos(degrees) - coordinates.y * sin(degrees);
new.y = coordinates.x * sin(degrees) + coordinates.y * cos(degrees);
```

But new.x and new.y aren't right.

I also tried this, multiplying the modelview by (new.x, new.y, 0, 1):

```
GLdouble modelview[16], NEWVERTEX[4];
glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview);

nmview[0] = modelview[0] * new.x + modelview[4] * new.y + modelview[8] * 0 + modelview[12] * 1;
nmview[1] = modelview[1] * new.x + modelview[5] * new.y + modelview[9] * 0 + modelview[13] * 1;
nmview[2] = modelview[2] * new.x + modelview[6] * new.y + modelview[10] * 0 + modelview[14] * 1;
nmview[3] = modelview[3] * new.x + modelview[7] * new.y + modelview[11] * 0 + modelview[15] * 1;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "aren't right"?

Comment: I mean that my rectangle is positioned in (0,5,0), and if I apply a 90 rotation, its center should be (-0.75,2.25,0) and these are the values that I need to get after the rotation. PS: the rectangle's scale is (0.5,1.5,0.5).

Answer (score 1):

First: OpenGL is a localized rasterizer, which only knows about point, lines and triangles. In OpenGL there are no geometrical objects and there is no scene.

Second: From the first immediately follows that OpenGL does not do collision detection and that there is nothing you can "change" in an object on the OpenGL side. You have to do collision detection yourself or using a 3rd party library implementing thing. All changes in the scene are reflected by redrawing the whole thing with OpenGL.

---

P.S.: The question is sort of a FAQ.

Comment: First: I did not mention that I need openGL to know my cubes or any polygon, and did not mention anything about scene.
Second: I also did not say that I do collision detection using any openGL function, it is just simple math, once you have the center of a polygon, which openGL does provide, for instance, from translatef(1,1,1) glutWireCube(1) you can say you have a 1x1x1 cube which center is positioned at (1,1,1).